# What is a good way of making usernames case insensitive in Python? (Beginner Level)

Tags: python, list, if-statement

I'm still a programming student so this might be very easy for you to answer.

I'm writing some code from the book 'Python Crash Course'. The task I'm on has me 'Make sure
my comparison is case insensitive. If 'John' has been used, 'JOHN' should not be accepted.
To do this you need to make a copy of current_users containing the lowercase versions of
all existing users.'

Which in my code I have. Except it doesn't work.

```
current_users = ['ted', 'jed', 'red', 'ned', 'dr fred']

new_users = ['ted', 'jed', 'bernard', 'hoagie', 'laverne']

for username in new_users:
    if username in current_users:
        print(f"Username {username} is unavailable. Please choose a different username.")
    else:
        print(f"Username {username} is available for use.")
```

Output: Username ted is unavailable. Please choose a different username.
Username jed is unavailable. Please choose a different username.
Username bernard is available for use.
Username hoagie is available for use.
Username laverne is available for use.
[Finished in 0.3s]

If I change 'ted' to 'Ted' or 'TED' it outputs:

Username Ted is available for use.
Username TED is available for use.

It shouldn't. Have I missed something?
Or did Python lose the function for case insensitivity in a recent update?

EDIT -
Thanks for the solutions.

Comment: What "function for case insensitivity" are you talking about? There is nothing in your code that is in any way related to case insensitivity.

Comment: The code is comparing new_users to current_users. My intention is to compare case sensitivity of the usernames, i.e. make sure you don't choose the same username as someone else. Right now the comparison is case sensitive, so the same username with different letters is accepted. Please read the question properly.

Comment: Jorg I realise that there's no code directly relating to case insensitivity. I was hoping for a solution that gave my code case insensitivity.

Comment: @MartinRombach the exercise is already pointing you towards a solution:  "To do this you need to make a copy of current_users containing the lowercase versions of all existing users." In general, if you want your comparisons to be case-insensitive, you convert the data that you are storing to the same case, e.g., any users you store should be stored after being converted to lowercase, *and then you convert the string you are checking to lowercase as well.* That's the key point.

Comment: I am still struggling to understand your question, particularly this part "Or did Python lose the function for case insensitivity in a recent update?" How did you come to the conclusion that it was a problem with the Python version? If I understand this correctly, your code was working fine, then you updated Python, and then it stopped working. Is that understanding correct? Because I don't see anything in your code that would have broken during any of the recent Python versions. (Your code will break in Python 3.5 and earlier, though.)

Comment: Basically 'Did Python lose the function' is a stupid question I said because I'm a noobie. There was a solution to be found, and because I couldn't find a solution written down for me or didn't spend enough time figuring it out for myself, I asked whether Python was broken. I didn't know how to do case insensitivity in Python, that's it really.

Comment: For the record, solutions for PCC exercises are here: https://ehmatthes.github.io/pcc_2e/solutions/solutions/

Answer (score 1):

I would so something like this:

```
current_users = ['ted', 'jed', 'red', 'ned', 'dr fred']

new_users = ['ted', 'JED', 'bernard', 'hoagie', 'laverne']

for username in map(str.lower, new_users):
    if username in map(str.lower, current_users):
        print(f"Username {username} is unavailable. Please choose a different username.")
    else:
        print(f"Username {username} is available for use.")
```

Basically converting `username` and all usernames in `current_users` to the same case

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code :

```
current_users = ['ted', 'jed', 'red', 'ned', 'dr fred']

new_users = ['ted', 'jed', 'bernard', 'hoagie', 'laverne']

for username in new_users:
    if username.lower() in [current_user.lower() for current_user in current_users]:
        print(f"Username {username} is unavailable. Please choose a different username.")
    else:
        print(f"Username {username} is available for use.")
```